# HTML issues in IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have written a html code for login as follwing

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page">
    <div class="aLogin">
        <label>User Name : </label>
        <input type="text" class="lname" />
        <label>Password : </label>
        <input type="password" class="lpwd" />
        <input type="submit" class="logSubmit" value="LOGIN" />
        <p class="lalert">test alert</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and written jQuery for validation.It replace the alert(here i used `<p class="lalert">test alert</p>`) dynamically.
  The problem is, when i run this in IE, the alert message was displayed twice. But in other browsers no problem.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.logSubmit').click(function(){
    var name = $('.lname').val();
    var pwd = $('.lpwd').val();
    $.post("/login.php",{name:name,pwd:pwd}).success(function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('.lalert').fadeIn('slow');
        if(obj.success == 1){
            $('.lalert').css('color','#067800');
            $('.lname').val('');
            $('.pwd').val('');
            $('.lalert').html(obj.msg);
        }else{
            $('.lalert').css('color','#CC0000');
            $('.lalert').html(obj.msg);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**login.php**

```
 <?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
   $err['success'] = 0;
   $err['msg'] = '';
   if($name != 'admin'){
   $err['msg'] = 'Invalid Name';
   }else if($pwd != 'admin'){
   $err['msg'] = 'Invalid Password';
   }else{
   $err['success'] = 1;
   $err['msg'] = 'Success';
   }
   echo json_encode($err);
?>
```

I can't found why this happening. Can anybody help me..?

Comment: where is jQuery code? post that

Comment: It will probably have attached the event handler twice for some reason but without the jQuery code that's a guess.

Comment: put all your code in jsfiddle then we can figure out i guess.

Comment: What does your console or firebug say? ...try adding event.preventDefault(); inside your click handler function

Comment: @shershen I added event.preventDefault() method.But the problem not solved. Till IE displays the alert twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.The problem happens due to **Empty Text Node**. IE8 generates **Empty Text Node** for line breaks after `<input>,<select>,<img>` tags.

I removed that spaces after the tags and now the problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Hi You have forgot to write the "return false".

```
$('.logSubmit').click(function(){ 
    var name = $('.lname').val(); 
    var pwd = $('.lpwd').val(); 
    $.post("/login.php",{name:name,pwd:pwd}).success(function(data){ 
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
        $('.lalert').fadeIn('slow'); 
        if(obj.success == 1){ 
            $('.lalert').css('color','#067800'); 
            $('.lname').val(''); 
            $('.pwd').val(''); 
            $('.lalert').html(obj.msg); 
        }else{ 
            $('.lalert').css('color','#CC0000'); 
            $('.lalert').html(obj.msg); 
        } 
    }); 
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: Stop (Mis)Using Return False: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @Hermant I used 'return false' in this case.. but the same problem occured again

Comment: @vinu
Put debugger and debug the code .So that you can trace where that Extra Alert is coming :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to use instead of using `$('.logSubmit').click(function(){ ...}`

use below syntax

```
$('.logSubmit').unbind('click').click(function(){ .....}
```

this may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **return false;** to your .logSubmit -click binder. Also, you could try replacing the submit-typed input with a <button> since submits are related to forms (submitting) and this is not the case in your situation.

Comment: **return false;** is bad practice and ambiguous - in this context the best way of preventing default behaviour is **event.preventDefault()**

Comment: I definitely agree with the `<button>` idea; it is a better match for what you are doing since you don't have a `<form>` element.